# How to make Kimono Labs not skip blank table cells?

Tags: web-scraping, kimono

I've made a [Kimono Labs scraper](https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/6a0es426) to grab data from [this website](https://www.dha.gov.au/dha-stock-list) which has a few tables with empty cells.

Rather than returning that empty cell, the scraper is returning the next value down the list,  so the values in the rows don't correspond to what's in the html table. How do I adjust the settings so that the data stays ordered correctly?

To illustrate, here's what's happening.

```html
Original    Kimono

  1 2 3     1 2 3 
a x y z   a x y z 
b n   o   b n e o
c d e f   c d   f
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the "Modify Results" tab in your API dashboard and create a simple javascript routine (IF...THEN) that checks if the data is "nil" and instead placed a "-" to fill in the cell that was empty.

The great thing is that you can see the results in realtime as you make your function, so you can see if its working.